# What's up with my bootstrap scrollspy?

Tags: jquery, scrollspy

I just want to try Bootstrap Navbar's scrollspy, but it doesn't work. And whichever the menu I click, the `<li><a href="section4"></li>` item always is active. If I delete date-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" in body and script on the bottom, li active is fine.

```
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TEST</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '#myNavbar',
            offset: 50
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, html file need to add **`<!DOCTYPE html>`** on the file top. And scrollspy works.

Comment: designates the file as HTML5 - therefore able to render the bootstrap function

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the jQuery in the document ready wrapper

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '#myNavbar',
            offset: 50
        });
})
```

also I spotted this in other documentation, which you might not have in your CSS:

**Requires relative positioning: The element with data-spy="scroll" requires the CSS position property, with a value of "relative" to work properly.**

Comment: I do have css style with a value of "relative" body position. Also, I wrap the jQuery in the document ready wrapper, it still doesn't work.